# AttributeError: module 'lacosmicx' has no attribute 'lacosmicx'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just installed lacosmicx and trying to use it in my code (python 3.7).
import lacosmicx doesn't cause any issue but when lacosmicx but when I use it in a function, e.g.: `myDash.fix_cosmic_rays()` I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-a48815bcfe29> in <module>
----> 1 myDash.fix_cosmic_rays()

~/Orion/HELPDESK/wfc3_dash/wfc3_dash/reduce_dash.py in fix_cosmic_rays(self, rm_custom, flag, **lacosmic_param)
    485             verbose = True
    486         #Have lacosmicx locate cosmic rays
--> 487         crmask, clean = lacosmicx.lacosmicx(flt_full[1].data, gain=gain, readnoise=readnoise, 
    488                                     objlim = objlim,
    489                                     pssl = pssl,

AttributeError: module 'lacosmicx' has no attribute 'lacosmicx'
```

I really appreciate if someone can help with this error.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `crmask, clean = lacosmicx(flt_full[1].data, ...`. remove the extra `lacosmicx`

Comment: Thanks! Here, `crmask, clean = lacosmicx(flt_full[1].data, ..` is included as the in-built function, `fix_cosmic_rays()` in a data reduction s/w. So I'm not sure if it's a good idea to change it.
In the meantime, I installed `lacosmicx` and tried to run this on another computer (unfortunately, I can't work longer on that computer--limited space) and it worked perfectly. So I assume I have done something wrong when I install `lacosmicx`. Any thoughts on what I may have done wrong?